# Using drawImage with a video as a source appears to only copy one pixel?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, drawimage

I have a video that's streaming parts of a video into a `MediaSource` and playing it. I have a canvas that I want to draw the video on an then overlay some effects. However, in my handler, the call to `drawImage`, while it works, it only appears to copy a single pixel. The video itself plays fine.

I have a screenshot from my app, which has the source video next to the destination canvas element:
[image: video and canvas side-by-side]

As you can sorta see, the solid color of the canvas is the color of the very first pixel of the source video.

The actual code in question looks similar to this:

```
  startWatch() {
    this.timer = setInterval(this.copyFrame.bind(this), 1000 / this.fps)
  }

  copyFrame() {
    const { width, height } = this.video.getBoundingClientRect()
    // I've tried the 3, 5, and 9 argument versions of this function
    // width is 300 and height is 168.75.
    this.ctx.drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, width, height)
  }
```

(where `this.video` is a `video` element)

This code does "work" in that the canvas's color does update over time as the video plays.  But it's always just the initial pixel. So the timing loop works, but the `drawImage` call isn't doing what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** Using `const { width, height }` may not be correct. Check the values you are given.
What happens if you `console.log` the **width** or **height** values, are they correct/expected numbers?

**(2)** *"...But the `drawImage` call isn't doing what I expect."*

```
ctx.drawImage( someElement, 0, 0, A1, A2, 0, 0, B1, B2 );
```

Consider the above code,

- The **first width/height** (A1/A2) is for **how much of the input** to draw (it must match size of input's own width/height, otherwise cropping or margins will occur). Eg: `A1 == 720` if input video is 720 pixels wide.
- The **second width/height** (B1/B2) is for **how much resize of the output** to draw. Usually you want to fill entire canvas area so **use canvas dimensions** (aspect ratio is left to coder to implement as preferred).

In your shown code, your `const { width, height }` is either

- Giving too small a number for A1/A2 params (it samples one pixel)
- Giving too large a number for B1/B2 params (it stretches output so large that one pixel fills the canvas).

**Possible solutions:**

Try (if you must use bounding rectangle):

```
function copyFrame() 
{
    //# width is 300 and height is 168.75.
    //const { width, height } = this.video.getBoundingClientRect()
    
    let myRect = this.video.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    this.ctx.drawImage( this.video, 0, 0, 
                        this.video.videoWidth, this.video.videoHeight, 
                        0, 0, myRect.width, myRect.height);
}
```

Alternativey you could just draw the picture into canvas size:

```
function copyFrame() 
{
    //# assuming your Canvas is called "this.cnvs"
    this.ctx.drawImage( this.video, 0, 0, 
                        this.video.videoWidth, this.video.videoHeight, 
                        0, 0, this.cnvs.width, this.cnvs.height);
}
```

For aspect ratio you can use the below formula (swap all width & height references for a new `drawn_width`)

```
myRatio = ( vid_height / vid_width ); 
drawn_height = ( myCanvas_width * myRatio );
```

Comment: I honestly don't know why this wasn't apparent to me before, because I double checked the numbers that came off `getBoundingClientRect()`, but the height and width were strings (`"300px"` and `"168.75px"`). When I changed them to static numbers, it works fine. Thanks for giving me a reason to triple check.

Comment: Glad it's solved. Yeah that happens. I know what you mean. I got it from setting `style=` of a video tag in JS and forgot the "px" part when setting positions, spent days thinking the problem was nested Divs and that maybe the parent was somehow overriding the child's own pos. Never mind parent of parent etc. When it finally "clicked" it was so obvious I used Decimals instead of Strings, yes we should triple check. The problem is also a **silent error** (code ignored) so you just get no change on web page when values are edited thus adding even more confusion.